# How to create black color in Eevee without any reflections?

Tags: materials, shaders, light, reflection

I try to make a a scence where I want an object not to be affected by any lighting, reflections etc... [image]

Here is the picture and the black planet should not contain anything but black.

I would be so happy if there is an answer to this.

Cheers
Robin

Answer (score 3):

To make an object that receives no shading, just plug the color directly into the Material Output with no shader in between.

As you can see from the image, the black planet is surrounded by lights and an emission object (I put planes to show that there in fact lights there). You can see with bloom on, that there will still be some color bleed-over, but there is no "reflection" on the black planet:

[image: Glow1]

Here is the same thing without bloom (for reference):

[image: Glow2]

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much! :)